# Run docker container always with --network host

Tags: docker

Beginner docker user here.

Is there a way that I create a docker image that when you run it it will ALWAYS run with the --network host options?

So that when I do docker run mydockerimage it will automatically do docker run --network host mydockerimage?

Comment: No. The image is decoupled from the way you operate it. For good reasons, IMO.

Comment: Host networking is almost never necessary, and it disables some of Docker's key networking features.  You shouldn't normally need it at all.  You could consider using a tool like Docker Compose that will let you put runtime options like this into a file so you don't have to type them repeatedly, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very strange request but one possibility is to override the `docker` function in your `~/.bashrc` file by appending this snippet:

```
docker() {
  if [ "$1" == "run" ]; then
     for var in "$@"
     do
        if [ "$var" == "mydockerimage" ]; then
           trigger=true      
        fi    
     done
     if [ "$trigger" == "true" ]; then
        /usr/local/bin/docker "$1" --network host "${@:2}"
        return
     fi
  fi
  /usr/local/bin/docker "$@"
}
```